# How to add legend corresponding to geom_hline(yintercept = log(2000)) in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using `geom_hline(yintercept = log(2000), linetype = "dotdash")` in ggplot2 to add a horizontal line at `y = log(2000)` in the plot (attached below).

What I want is to display the legend "log(2000)" at the left side of the y axis corresponding to the dash line. Any ideas?

[image]

The R code of the plot is given below:

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales) 
set.seed(10)
varx <- rep(c("group1", "group2"), each = 3)
vary <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)    
poi <- sample(20:30, 6)
upper <- sample(40:50, 6)
lower <- sample(1:10, 6)

dat <- data.frame(varx, vary, poi, upper, lower)
dat
#    varx vary poi upper lower
#1 group1    A  25    43     2
#2 group1    B  23    42     6
#3 group1    C  29    45     3
#4 group2    A  30    50     4
#5 group2    B  20    44     1
#6 group2    C  21    47    10

pp <- ggplot(dat, aes(colour = varx, y = poi, x = vary)) 

limits <- aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower)

pp  + geom_point(aes(shape=varx), position = position_dodge(0.3), size = 2) + 
  ## dodge make the lines not stack upon each other
  geom_errorbar(limits, size = 1, width = 0.15, position = position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  theme_bw() + ## Get rid of the grey background
  geom_hline(yintercept = log(2000), linetype = "dotdash") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 60)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 19)) + 
  theme(legend.justification= c(1, 0), 
        legend.position = c(1, 0.75),
        legend.key = element_blank(),## Get rid of the legend box 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha(0.0001))) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

Comment: Maybe adding `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(35, seq(0, 60, 10))))`?

Comment: @lukeA, thank you very much for the suggestion, but I am sorry that I did not make myself clear and I have edited my question. I want to display the character "log(2000)" instead of a number, any idea?

Comment: building on @lukeA's comment `scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(log(2000), seq(0, 60, 10))),labels=c(0,"log(2000)",seq(10,60,10)))`

Comment: @scoa, that solves my problem, thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building on @lukeA's comment

```
pp + scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(log(2000), seq(0, 60, 10))),labels=c(0,"log(2000)",seq(10,60,10)))
```

[image]